# Google Analytics Facebook Campaign URL Parameters being treated as search filter?

Tags: html, google-analytics

I have a link that that takes you to a product landing page and looks something like this:

> shop.this.com/couches.html?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=...

And when I take out the URL Parameters after the "?" that handle the GA tracking, the page works fine, but with the campaign data in there the page doesn't load the content. I believe this is happening because the page is treating the URL Params as search filters, and obviously when you're browsing couches, there's not going to be a couch named Facebook. Any thoughts on how to research and resolve this issue? Is this an HTML issue?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly For instance, you're on a product landing page with a bunch of different couches of different brands, types, etc. And when the GA URL Params are in there, it shows the page itself, but it doesn't show any content on the page. It's my assumption that it doesn't show content because it's seeing these parameters and treating them like a user searched for something in the search bar. Though I'm not sure.

Comment: To me this sounds like it's likely an issue with server-side scripting/config, e.g. `.htaccess` not properly redirecting/building urls, or whatever CMS you are using, not properly parsing URLs or something. I'm not psychic, but I seriously doubt your site search is utilizing GA params.